# Error : "cannot read property 'nodename' of undefined" While converting html Table

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to convert an HTML Table to KendoGrid but getting an error while executing this

```js
$("#ReportExport").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: ["excel"],
    filterable: { mode: "row" },
    pageSize: 25,
    sortable: true,
    columnMenuInit(e) {
        e.container.find('li[role="menuitemcheckbox"]:nth-child(1)').remove();
        e.container.find('li[role="menuitemcheckbox"]:nth-child(4)').remove();
    },
    columnMenu: {
        filterable: false
    },
    reorderable: true,
    resizable: true,
    pageable: {
        alwaysVisible: true,
        pageSizes: [25, 100]
    },
});
```

and the console says this
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined at N (kendo.all.js:7692)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this one.
Actually I was unaware of the difference between `$("#GridName").KendoGrid()` and `$("#GridName").data('kendoGrid')`.
First one basically initialize the grid.Later on,if you want to operate the grid,You have to get it first in a variable by using second method.
So the problem lies here

```js
columnMenuInit(e) {
        e.container.find('li[role="menuitemcheckbox"]:nth-child(1)').remove();
        e.container.find('li[role="menuitemcheckbox"]:nth-child(4)').remove();
    }
```

Since the method I was using is for initialization,so grid was unable to perform the required functionality.
Thanks to Diogo Peres for giving me right direction.

Answer (score 2):

This error can be due to the element not being available when the script tries to access it.

You can try to insert your code on a document.ready function to make sure your DOM is loaded or check if the element is available before running your code.